# Apple News API published articles got FAILED_PROCESSING

Tags: python, apple-news

**UPDATE**: This was a temporary issue last a couple of days.

I developed a python apple news api client and I successfully pushed articles to preview in my apple news channel.
Anyway, when I check the state of those articles, most of them is FAILED_PROCESSING. Only one went LIVE but without images (animated GIFs).

There aren't details about the error and I can't guess what is wrong. Articles look good in News Preview tool.
Does anyone have any clue about? Any way to debug the issue?

Thanks!

```
   >>>api_key = 'xxxxx'
   >>>secret_key = 'xxxx'
   >>>channel_id = 'xxxx'
   >>>client = ApiClient(api_key, secret_key, channel_id=channel_id)
   >>>articles = client.search_articles()
   >>>articles
   {u'data': [{u'accessoryText': None,
   u'createdAt': u'2016-04-27T08:36:35Z',
   u'id': u'xxxxx',
   u'isCandidateToBeFeatured': False,
   u'isDevelopingStory': False,
   u'isPreview': True,
   u'isSponsored': False,
   u'links': {u'channel': u'https://news-api.apple.com/channels/xxxxx',
    u'sections': [u'https://news-api.apple.com/sections/xxxxx'],
    u'self': u'https://news-api.apple.com/articles/xxxxx'},
   u'modifiedAt': u'2016-04-27T08:36:47Z',
   u'revision': u'AAAAAAAAAAD//////////w==',
   u'shareUrl': u'https://apple.news/xxxxxx',
   u'state': u'FAILED_PROCESSING',
   u'title': u'Test 1',
   u'type': u'article'},

  ....

  {u'accessoryText': None,
   u'createdAt': u'2016-04-14T07:07:27Z',
   u'id': u'xxxx',
   u'isCandidateToBeFeatured': False,
   u'isDevelopingStory': False,
   u'isPreview': True,
   u'isSponsored': False,
   u'links': {u'channel': u'https://news-api.apple.com/channels/xxxx',
    u'sections': [u'https://news-api.apple.com/sections/xxxx'],
    u'self': u'https://news-api.apple.com/articles/xxxx'},
   u'modifiedAt': u'2016-04-14T07:07:45Z',
   u'revision': u'AAAAAAAAAAD//////////w==',
   u'shareUrl': u'https://apple.news/xxxx',
   u'state': u'LIVE',
   u'title': u"Test 2",
   u'type': u'article'}],
 u'links': {u'next': None,
  u'self': u'https://news-api.apple.com/channels/xxxx/articles'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you suggest that processing proceeded for articles not containing images, possibly your problem is related to not using bundled images.

Support for remote images was added only as of **2016-05-04**:

> Added support for remote images under Apple New Format Document and Resources for the [Create Article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/News_API_Ref/CreateArticle.html) endpoint

For reference, see

- [Apple News API Reference: Revision History](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/News_API_Ref/RevisionHistory.html)
- [Apple News API Reference: Create Article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/News_API_Ref/CreateArticle.html)

Comment: my API as an option to upload bundle images or just using remote urls. The problem wasn't related and it seemed a temporary problem on their side. They're still in beta version.

Comment: It works fine for us, we've already published a couple of thousand articles using their API.

Comment: yes I forgot to mention that this was a temporary issue!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Apple News error messages aren't very useful.

This is a checklist that is by no means complete, but may help you diagnose some issues.

[Common Errors in Apple Native Format (ANF) Files](https://medium.com/@thehaoran/common-errors-in-apple-native-format-anf-files-5ea8cb62e9de#.al5ox1ji7)

Note that URLs are now allowed instead of bundled images as of the most recent Apple News update.

Comment: Thanks. It can be useful! They definitely need to improve error messages.